# Does iron(VI) fluoride exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

Why does $\ce{FeF6}$ not exist? There are hexavalent iron compounds, so that is not the problem. There is the $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}$ ion, so there doesn't seem to be a steric problem.

Comment: Maybe reading about bonding characteristics of [Potassium Ferrate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_ferrate) may help.

Comment: No, it doesn't, as far as it is possible to prove a negative. Nor do CrF6, MnF7 or CoF5. And note your steric argument is not correct, Fe3+ is appreciably bigger than Fe6+, as far as those terms have any meaning in chemical environments.

Comment: Not an answer. But $\ce{FeF3}$ as a crystal *already is* something like $\ce{FeF6}$, in the sense that each iron is bound to six fluorine atoms; the lattice is linked via $\ce{-F-}$ bridges. The existence of $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}$ is more of an argument for $\ce{[FeF6]^3-}$ than $\ce{FeF6}$.

Comment: Food for thought: The dimer of iron(III) fluoride doesn't exist(unlike [iron(III) chloride](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166128099004029)), but the anion, $\ce{[Fe2F6]^-}$ does exist consisting of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and $\ce{Fe^3+}$ ions and it form salts like [$\ce{[NH4]Fe2F6}$](https://materials.springer.com/isp/crystallographic/docs/sd_1830851).

Answer (score 5):

Besides steric factors related to the small size of the transition metal core, we could be seeing an electronic effect described [in this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/126788/17175).  Iron is fairly early in the transition metal series, so when pushed beyond the $+3$ oxidation state it has few $d$ electrons in the central core.  As explained in the referenced answer, this makes the iron strongly pi-electron accepting, and therefore more favorable for combining with a stronger pi-donor ligand such as oxide instead of fluoride.

Comment: Thank you!  So: what about FeO2F2  or FeOF4..?

Comment: You may want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-valent_iron.  Organic compounds do allow a wider variety of ligands, but all the examples given there (with iron in oxidation states of +4 to +6) still involve pi-donor ligands from Groups 15 and 16, primarily oxygen and nitrogen.

Comment: @ThomasForster Not exactly FeO2F2 but there are similar types of compounds: [$\ce{Fe3(OF)2}$](https://www.osti.gov/dataexplorer/biblio/dataset/1672834), [$\ce{Li2Fe4OF8}$](https://www.osti.gov/dataexplorer/biblio/dataset/1308370), [$\ce{FeSbO2F2}$](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.inorgchem.7b00301?src=recsys).

Comment: @nilay good finds, but no Fe(VI).  They are just Fe(II) and Fe(III).

Comment: This shows that iron can't achieve +6 o.s. that easily.