# Is Chromium(VI) fluoride able to be synthesized properly?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, oxidation-state

[Chromium(VI) fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_hexafluoride), also known as chromium hexafluoride is a possible chemical compound with a chromium atom attached to 6 fluorine atoms. It has been unsuccessfully synthesized a number of times by heating up chromium to 400 °C in a fluorine atmosphere at 20 megapascals of pressure and freezing it as it was formed but this was still a failure as this instead produces chromium(V) fluoride or chromium pentafluoride. Is the following possible?

The predicted reaction was:

$$\ce{Cr + 3 F2 -> CrF6}$$

Instead, the following reaction was happening:

$$\ce{2 Cr + 5 F2 -> 2 CrF5}$$

Comment: I assume that CrF6 is such a strong oxidizer that it easily oxidizes CrF4 to give two CrF5.

Comment: So what is the question? Your reference states clearly, "CrF6 has yet to be synthesized." It does not state it is impossible. Proving a negative is a  bit difficult.

Comment: Apparently, chromium [favors oxide instead of fluoride ligands at such a high oxidation state.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/126788/17175)

Comment: Check these papers: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ic00052a007 ... https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ic00026a002 .... https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1984/c3/c39840001355/unauth#!divAbstract

Comment: Also, some papers from the late 19th century reported that CrF6 is a deep-red vapor which condensed to a blood-red liquid at low temperature. It is made by reacting lead chromate, calcium fluoride and sulfuric acid($\ce{PbCrO4 + 3CaF2 + 4H2SO4 -> PbSO4 + 3CaSO4 + 4H2O + CrF6}$) It strongly fumes in air and decomposes on contact with water/moisture to form chromium trioxide and hydrofluoric acid. (But then again, this is from a very old source, so this info. maybe outdated).

Answer (score 2):

Both steric and electronic factors inhibit the formation of chromium hexafluoride.

- **Steric factors.** Chromium, like most transition metals, commonly forms octahedral complexes. But in the fourth period where chromium lies these octahedral complexes tend to occur with relatively low oxidation states like $+3$ for chromium. The metal center would be smaller in an oxidation state as high as $+6$, and possibly we would need a fifth or higher period metal to get the center large enough to continue to coordinate octahedrally. So we can get hexafluorides of molybdenum and tungsten but as yet not chromium.
- **Electronic factors.** In [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/126788/17175) early transition metals are identified as strong pi acceptor and therefore prefer oxo complexes (with a better pi-donor ligand) over fluoro complexes. This does not prevent the synthesis of a hexafluoride (as we saw above with molybdenum and tungsten) or perhaps even a fluoro-cation (which would avoid the steric issues that a neutral hexafluoride would have with chromium). But it does imply that such compounds are likely to break down at the drop of an oxide-bearing hat. The respective Wikipedia pages for $\ce{MoF6}$ and $\ce{WF6}$ indicate that these hydrolyze in water, the tungsten compound specifically being reported to form oxyfluorides and ultimately the oxide. Presumably $\ce{CrF6}$ would react similarly with water, to form chromic acid and then, since that acid is strong, the anions $\ce{Cr2O7^{2-}}$ and $\ce{CrO4^{2-}}$.